# how to define the value of a radio button as a mail object?

Tags: input, label

i want to  define the chosen option as the object of the sent Email .(https://i.stack.imgur.com/jX9J7.png)

This is the code :

Apply For Which Post?
                    
                        
                        
                       Web Designer
                      
                    
                  
                  
                  Support Engineer
                
                
                  
                  
                  Web Developer
                
                
                  
                  
                  Support Technician 
                
        
                
                  
                  
                  Digital Marketer
                
                
               
                
                     Upload your curriculum here if you are interested

```
     <!--form action="mailto:ishrakashouri5@gmail.com" method="GET"> </form-->
```